# spidermonkey mozjs-31.2.0: js-config.h didn't install - how do I fix it

Tags: mozilla, spidermonkey

Building helloworld test program after installing mozjs fails with the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/mozjs-31/js/TypeDecls.h:23:23: fatal error: js-config.h: No such file or directory 
 #include "js-config.h"
```

It is in my build directory:

```
mozjs-31.2.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/dist/include/js-config.h 
mozjs-31.2.0/js/src/build_OPT.OBJ/js/src/js-config.h
```

but make install didn't transfer it.

```
$ js-config --cflags --libs 
-std=gnu++0x -include /usr/local/include/mozjs-31/js/RequiredDefines.h -I/usr/local/include/mozjs-31 
-L${libdir} -l${JS_LIBRARY_NAME}  -lm -ldl 

$ uname -a 
Linux greg-softsprocket 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Everything seemed to build and install without a problem. Can I just copy it to `/usr/local/include/mozjs-31`? Should I be downloading and building a different source? This one was `https://people.mozilla.org/~sstangl/mozjs-31.2.0.rc0.tar.bz2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - you can copy js-config.h and a new code repo has been issued that fixes the problem.